# Select2 local pagination/infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, pagination, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 version 4 and have a list with about 16,000 items. Predictably this is quite slow (take over 5 seconds to open sometimes) so I'm trying to find a way to speed this up.

Currently my data is being retrieved as an array using an ajax request and then inserted into the select2/dom using a for loop/appending.

```
    $('#select').select2({
        placeholder: "Select"
    });

    $.ajax("/Example/Data", {
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .success(function (data, status, xhr) {
        var option = '<option></option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var curId = data[i].district_id;
            var curDist = data[i].district_name;
            var curState = data[i].state_short;
            option += '<option value="' + curId + '">' + curDist + '('+ curState + ')' + ' - ' + curId + '</option>';
        }
        $('#select').append(option);
    });
```

I've been trying to find a way to simply retrieve the data using the ajax request as I am doing now and then paginate/infinite scroll with the local but have been unable to do so

I've tried implementing this exactly: http://embed.plnkr.co/sUt9zi but I can't get it to work (maybe because it's using select2 v3.4.5) so if we could get that or something like it to work with v4 that would be great.

Comment: 16k is really not that much for modern systems. there's no reason it should take that long. you should see if you can't optimize your query.

Comment: From your example it appears you are still pulling the entire 16k item dataset and attempting to generate dom elements one at a time. This is an intense operation, you will want to process smaller chunks. The select2 library documents their pagination pretty well here: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#pagination

Comment: i just realized you're not using sql.... well, you should. even with infinite scoll, it's not going to be any faster as you're still loading the whole thing all at once.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I am using sql (the ajax makes a query using sql) but the query is simply a select *, so essentially returning the entire table. How can this be optimized

Comment: The query is likely not the problem, this is an issue with appending thousands of items to the DOM. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/34248/ This is a small example of only appending 3000 items taking a second. DOM manipulation takes some time, changing this to 16k nearly crashes the browser. You will need to look into pagination / loading incrementally.

Comment: the query is precisely the problem. he is selecting all rows which is causing thousands of dom appendages.. he needs to optimize the query by only selecting rows that match the text. use `select * from mytable where column LIKE %query%` that `like` condition will drastically speed up your project.

Comment: here's the answer to your actual question, but as we've noted, it won't speed anything up.. plnkr.co/edit/2WxyaicYuWmY7xCkZmrz?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the 'slowness' you will need to mitigate creating and appending all 16k option elements at once. In order to do this the `select2` library documents pagination using AJAX here: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#pagination

However, using the example you mentioned we can use a local dataset by doing something similar to:

```js
var testData = [];
var dataSize = 1000;

// Instead of doing this use the AJAX call to poulate the data.
for (var i=0; i < dataSize; i++) {
 testData.push({ text: `Data: ${i}`});
}

/* 
  Because you are sourcing your data via AJAX, this will 
    go in the success callback
*/
$("#testSelect").select2({
  data: testData,
  query: function(q) {
    var pageLength = 50;

    // Get a page sized slice of data from the results of filtering the data set.      
    var paged = this.data.slice((q.page - 1) * pageLength, q.page * pageLength);

    q.callback({
      results: paged,
      more: this.data.length >= q.page * pageLength
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="testSelect" style="width: 200px"/>
```

**Consider using server side to reduce the data instead**

You are already using a remote data source, but you will need to pass some parameters to indicate which set of data is now necessary. The documentation shows doing this like:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        page: params.page || 1
      }

      // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

The query properties is important to pass the current page. This allows you to set an `OFFSET` in your sql query. Assuming you are using mysql your endpoint would be making a query similar to:

```
function getPageOfData(pageNum) {
  var pageLength = 50;
  var pageStart = (pageNum - 1) * pageLength;
  var pageEnd = pageStart + pageLength;

  var query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ' + pageStart + ',' + pageEnd;
}
```

Server side pagination is a bit complicated to set up as it requires the client to pass these parameters and the server to reply with a limited data set, but it will be the best option for handling large-ish datasets like yours.

Comment: Great answer!

But, you should correct your last code block. The query should be look like this:

    var query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ' + pageStart + ',' + pageLength;